# Adding vectors with the same direction?

Tags: vectors

Taking into account this image:

[image]

You could say that the vector $\vec{FB}=\vec{FA}+\vec{AB}$. However, does this apply to vectors of the same direction too? For example, does $\vec{FC}=\vec{FO}+\vec{OC}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It is fine. No problem.

You can say 
$$FC=FO+OC$$
for any point $F, C, O.$

By the way, the followings are better.

$$\vec{FC}=\vec{FO}+\vec{OC}.$$

Comment: Yes, I just didn't know the stackexchange code for adding vector notation Thanks for the reply!

Comment: You can write $\vec{AB}$ if you type \vec{AB}. You are welcome!

Comment: Also, can I assume those triangles are equilateral?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Do you see why?

Comment: Well, it's a regular hexagon, meaning the angles are all initially 120 degrees. However, the triangles are made by splitting the hexagons angles in half. So since the two outer angles are 60 degrees, the angle at the origin point must be so too to add up to 180 degrees. I'm not sure if I can assume the triangles are split exactly in half though, so I'm not sure if that's a valid explanation.

Comment: You can see $OB=OC$ and $\angle BOC=60^\circ.$

Comment: So two equal sides and one 60 degree angle means it has to be equilateral?

Comment: Since $OB=OC$, the triangle is a isosceles triangle. So, $\angle{OBC}=\angle{OCB}=(180-60)/2=60.$

Comment: Ah yes, that makes sense. How exactly do I justify that $\angle{BOC}$ is 60 degrees, though?

Comment: You can see 360/6=60.

Comment: Ah, so it's alright to assume it's split into 6 even parts?

Comment: Yes, you can assume so.